# Extending a react Symbol(react.forward_ref) from leaflet-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm importing Popup from react-leaflet

```
import  { Marker, Map, Popup, TileLayer, ZoomControl, GeoJSON, ScaleControl} from 'react-leaflet'
```

and trying to extend it

```
class NewPopup extends Popup  {

    onPopupOpen = ({ popup }: { popup: LeafletElement }) => {
        if (popup === this.leafletElement) {
            console.log("Here open");
            this.onOpen()
        }
    }

    onPopupClose = ({ popup }: { popup: LeafletElement }) => {
        if (popup === this.leafletElement) {
            console.log("Here close");
            this.onClose()
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles fine, but when I run it in the browser I get the error "Super expression must either be null or a function, not object"

When I console.log the Popup object it looks like this

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.forward_ref), render: ƒ, apply: ƒ, bind: ƒ, call: ƒ, …}
```

Rather than a React component. Do I need to import it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/506) discusses why the following error occurs:

> Super expression must either be null or a function, not object

The short answer is: `Popup` component is not supported to be extended via inheritance in `react-leaflet` library. In fact even [React official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) encourages to prefer composition over inheritance:

> At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t
>   found any use cases where we would recommend creating component
>   inheritance hierarchies.
>
> Props and composition give you all the flexibility you need to
>   customize a component’s look and behavior in an explicit and safe way.
>   Remember that components may accept arbitrary props, including
>   primitive values, React elements, or functions.

Having said that, the following example demonstrates how to customize `Popup` component:
(it will print a message into console once the popup is closed or opened)

```
class MyPopup extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { map } = this.props.leaflet; //get map instance
    map.on("popupopen", e => {
      console.log(e.popup);
      console.log("Popup opened")
    });
    map.on("popupclose", e => {
      console.log(e.popup);
      console.log("Popup closed")
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <Popup {...this.props} />;
  }
}
```

`MyPopup` component needs to be wrapped with `withLeaflet` HOC in order to pass Leaflet context

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uun6rb)

Comment: I'm getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" from this line const { map } = this.props.leaflet;

Comment: @psykx, indeed, i forgot to mention `MyPopup`  needs to be wrapped in   `withLeaflet` HOC  in order to pass Leaflet context. The answer has been updated